# java: incompatible types: java.lang.Long cannot be converted to ValidFor

Tags: java, lombok

I have two classes

1. Builder for SpecContext object

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Value;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;


@Data
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SpecContext {

    private Long globalPriceId;

    private Long priceId;

    private ValidFor validFor;




    @JsonCreator
    public SpecContext(
            @JsonProperty(value = "globalPriceId")
            Long globalPriceId,
            @JsonProperty(value = "validFor")
            ValidFor validFor,
            @JsonProperty(value = "priceId")
            Long priceId
    ) {
        this.globalPriceId = globalPriceId;
        this.validFor = validFor;
        this.priceId = priceId;

    }

}
```

2. Builder for ValidFor object

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import utils.DateJsonDeserializer;
import utils.DateJsonSerializer;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@Value
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ValidFor {
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
    private LocalDateTime endDateTime;
    public static final String START_DATE_TIME = "startDateTime";
    public static final String END_DATE_TIME = "endDateTime";


    @JsonCreator
    public ValidFor(
            @JsonDeserialize(using = DateJsonDeserializer.class)
            @JsonSerialize(using = DateJsonSerializer.class)
            @JsonProperty(value = START_DATE_TIME)
                    LocalDateTime startDateTime,

            @JsonDeserialize(using = DateJsonDeserializer.class)
            @JsonSerialize(using = DateJsonSerializer.class)
            @JsonProperty(value = END_DATE_TIME)
                    LocalDateTime endDateTime)
            {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }




    public static ValidForBuilder builder() {
        return new ValidForBuilder();
    }

    public static class ValidForBuilder {
        private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
        private LocalDateTime endDateTime;

        public ValidForBuilder() {
        }

        public ValidForBuilder startDateTime(LocalDateTime startDateTime) {
            this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
            return this;
        }

        public ValidForBuilder endDateTime(LocalDateTime endDateTime) {
            this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
            return this;
        }

        public ValidFor build() {

            return new ValidFor(startDateTime, endDateTime);
        }
    }

}
```

I use it in an autotest:

```
void test() {

    SpecContext sp = SpecContext.builder()
            .globalPriceId(101928081L)
            .priceId(2L)
            .validFor(ValidFor.builder().
                    startDateTime(LocalDateTime.of(2019, 10, 10, 14, 15, 00))
                    .endDateTime(LocalDateTime.of(2025, 10, 10, 14, 15, 00))
                    .build())
            .build();
```

During complilation I got the error
`java: incompatible types: java.lang.Long cannot be converted to ValidFor`
I don't understand why globalPriceId and priceId are being tried to convert in ValidFor?

I tried to use Lombok @Builder for ValidFor but got the same error

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: where in your code do you get this issue?

Comment: I got it during building (build failed). It pointed on @Builder annotation in SpecContext class

Comment: I did some experiment and changed Long type for globalPriceId and priceId to Integer type and got the error `java: incompatible types: java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to ValidFor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lombok `@Builder` **requires** that you have a constructor that contains each and every field, **in the same order your fields are listed**. This is why `@Builder` will generate this for you, but if you want to write your own constructor, you can do that too. You did here, and your constructor's argslist *does not match up* - you have swapped orders: In your constructor, the order is: `[Long globalPriceId, ValidFor validFor, Long priceId]`, but in your fields the order is `[Long globalPriceId, Long priceId, ValidFor validFor]`.